# How can I prevent query params from accumulating each time I change the filter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, inertiajs

I have a problem with the accumulation of query params when I choose a new filter to my select.

How can I keep the current filter with each change ?

Here my select :

```js
import SelectInput from '@/Components/SelectInput';
import { ApplicationData } from '@/types/generated';
import { InertiaFormProps } from '@inertiajs/react/types/useForm';
import { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';
import { ApplicationSlugFilterFormProps } from '../Index';

interface ApplicationSlugFiltersProps extends PropsWithChildren {
  applications: ApplicationData[];
  form: InertiaFormProps<ApplicationSlugFilterFormProps>;
}

export default function ApplicationFilterSlug({ applications, form }: ApplicationSlugFiltersProps) {
  return (
    <SelectInput
      form="page-filters"
      name="filter[group.id]"
      value={form.data['filter[application_slug]']}
      className="!h-10"
      onChange={e => {
        form.setData('filter[application_slug]', e.currentTarget.value);
      }}
    >
      <option value="">Tous les groupes</option>
      {applications.map(applications => (
        <option key={applications.id} value={applications.slug}>
          {applications.name}
        </option>
      ))}
    </SelectInput>
  );
}
```

The inertia form :

```js
const filterForm = useForm<ApplicationSlugFilterFormProps>({
    'filter[name]': queryParameters.get('filter[name]') ?? '',
    'filter[application_slug]': queryParameters.get('filter[application_slug]') ?? '',
  });
```

The type used :

```js
export type ApplicationSlugFilterFormProps = {
  'filter[name]': string;
  'filter[application_slug]': string;
};
```

My base url :

`http://myapp.test/admin/settings/groups`

My base url with first filter :

`http://myapp.test/admin/settings/groups?filter%5Bname%5D=&filter%5Bapplication_slug%5D=tts`

My base path above with a new filter applied :

`http://myapp.test/admin/settings/groups?filter%5Bname%5D=&filter%5Bapplication_slug%5D=tts&filter%5Bname%5D=&filter%5Bapplication_slug%5D=workflow`

The goal is to make an url look like the second path and not have a duplicate filter at each changes.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object, part of the URL object.

1. parse the URL using `URL` constructor
2. use the `set` method on the url's `searchParams` object

> The `set()` method of the `URLSearchParams` interface sets the value associated with a given search parameter to the given value. **If there were several matching values, this method deletes the others. If the search parameter doesn't exist, this method creates it.**

3. convert the URL object back to a string

```js
// 1
const url = new URL("http://myapp.test/admin/settings/groups?filter%5Bname%5D=&filter%5Bapplication_slug%5D=tts")

// 2
url.searchParams.set("filter[application_slug]", "workflow")

// 3
console.log(String(url))
```

```
http://myapp.test/admin/settings/groups?filter%5Bname%5D=&filter%5Bapplication_slug%5D=workflow
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll implement it to my code

Answer (score 0):

It is better to rest the `useState` variable when inserting a new filter. Create a handler function in the select `onChange` event called `filterHandler`.

Then you can check the `form.data` and rest it. Finally, save it using `form.setData`.